# jquery autocomplete and jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-autocomplete

On my aspx page, I am trying to use autocomplete and validate that the form was filled out. However, when I use both libraries at the same time the autocomplete dropdown list is unable to be selected by mouse click but can be used with the arrow and enter keys. Is there anyway to use both of these packages together without this issue?

I copied the example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and added the validation.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myForm').validate();
            });

            function vaidateForm() {
                if (!$('#QAForm').valid()) return false;
                alert("IS VALID");
            };
        </script>
        <form id="myForm">
            <div id="AssignTo">
                <label for="tags" class="required">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
            </div>                            
         <input type="button"  onclick="vaidateForm()" value="Save" />
</form>






        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here: **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/G3Qqc/1/

Validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

This should fit your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate();
});


$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl" ],
    delay: 0
});

​
```

Comment: This works! but can you tell me what specifically was wrong. Was it that I was using jquery and jquery-ui or that I was trying to have a form without a submit button....

Comment: @segFault Glad it helped you :) Read the JQ validate plugin, see `class=required` tag in demo above and name and id tags as well, you will see the different :) lemme know how it goes

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to run your example:$("#registerForm").validate is not a function

$("#registerForm").validate();

Comment: @segFault where are you getting any error? Hope you have renamed that id to your `myform` etc. ` <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

Comment: i copied and pasted the example code inplace of my page. I get it once it tries to execute the onready js function that says form.validate

Comment: @segFault `B-)` see the 2 script source above add them to your page **OR** go to this link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation and now go to any example and click on the **source code** link you will see the libraries you need to include. that will get you flying `:)` in my example copy everything - css as well. rest should help